# using generics for view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have a view that I'd like to give a model to, but the model can be a possible of 2 types. Example:

```
public class Super {
  public string Name = "super";
}
public class Sub1 : Super {
  public string Name = "sub1";
}
public class sub2 : Super {
  public string Name = "sub2";
}
```

I'm trying to experiment with generics, and looking at some other questions I see I can do the following, however, am I declaring the variable inside the class correctly?

```
public class Generic<T> where T : Super {
  public T SubClass { get; set; } //is this ok?
}
```

if this is ok, how would I add such a class as the model to a view?

```
@model Generic<??>
<div>@Model.SubClass.Name</div>
```

is this even feasible, am I on the right track, or am I just kind of doing a whole bunch of nothing?

Comment: I don't think you need generics for this.  Replace `T` with `Super`.

Comment: You can do this, but I don't see any compelling reason to do so here.  Maybe you need to add some more, specific context?  As an aside, re-declaring `Name` will hide the member in the base class and possibly won't behave as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have your view use `Super` as the model:

```
@model Super
```

You'll be able to pass either `Sub1` or `Sub2` in since they both inherit from `Super`.

Answer (score 1):

Razor views don't support generic models - you can have specific generic like `IEnumerable<int>`, but you can't have `IEnumerable<T>`.

It looks like you really want regular inheritance with virtual methods and not generics.

```
public class Super {
  public virtual string Name {get {return "super";}}
}
public class Sub1 : Super {
  override public string Name {get {return "sub1";}}
}
```

And simply use `Super` as type of model

```
@model Super
<div>@Model.Name</div>
```

Additional note: generic classes have no inheritance relation to each other (`Generic<Super>` is not in any shape of form related to `Generic<Sub1>`) - so you can't specify "base" generic class and have it reasonable work for derived classes. Following model will not even allow to pass `Generic<Sub1>` (you may handle that with interface - read on "generics and covariance")

```
@model Generic<Super> @* can't pass instance of Generic<Sub1> *@
```